# two ternary expressions in one

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm trying to express these two ternary operators in one expression. Can someone help me?

```
    var longer = a.length > b.length ? a: b;
    var shorter = a.length > b.length ? b : a;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this mean you want to get two results from one expression? That is not possible.

Comment: As felix said, if your goal is to set two variables with the same expression, that's not gonna work.  If that isn't your goal, you might explain a bit more as to what you are after

Comment: Be more clear about what you want.

Comment: The goal was to set the vars longer and shorter in the same expression.

Comment: You could use the comma operator (and thus make it one expression) but it does not really improve anything. You still need to compute `longer` and `shorter` separately.

Comment: You should do it separately. One extra line of code means nothing until you try and maintain it later (or someone else does), at which point it can be extremely useful.

Comment: Incidentally, in ECMAScript `? :` is called a [conditional operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this since JavaScript 1.7 (its 1.8.5 now): [Destructuring assignment (Merge into own page/section)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_%28Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection%29).

As everyone could (possibly) imagine, the [cross-browser compatibility is abysmal](http://www.robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-1.7.html#destructuring-assignment). But since this is a homework question I'll leave it here as an answer.

Comment: In other words, you can't do this.

Comment: The fact you can does not mean you should.

Comment: @KenWhite: Of course you and Chuck are right in every way. But since he tagged this question as a homework I'll leave this here. He who give this question, if he is expecting such a way to solve, is most evil though.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible if you plan on declaring both variables in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the first expression an assignment that gets nested as the condition of the second.... but in this case, I think you should keep the two separate lines in order to avoid obfuscating your code.  Nesting the ternaries will not give you a performance boost and therefore serves no useful purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The clearest solution with the 2 values would be something like (may have to adjust the syntax):

```
[shorter, longer] = [a, b].sort(function(a, b) {return a.length > b.length});
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question was answered already. But, I have attempted it for fun,

```
shorter = ((a.length < b.length) && (longer = b))||((longer = a)&&false) ? a: b;
```

UPDATE:

As @MattWhipple suggests, you can make it shorter (you may see warning in the console)

```
((a.length < b.length) && (shorter = a) && (longer = b)) || ((shorter = b) && (longer = a))
```

Comment: If you did it without the ternary you could likely bind more legibly:
`((a.length < b.length) && (shorter = a) && (longer = b)) || ((shorter = b) && (longer = a))`

Comment: i did something similar first, but i got this warning in jsbin (http://jsbin.com/upadoc/1/edit) "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression".